# Regex remove both apostrophes if they exist in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I’m quit new to Regex but almost finished with my text mining script. Only one thing fails: I’m trying to remove the apostrophes between a word if they exist. I’m using re.sub for this.

For instance:

- ‘Apple’ needs to be Apple
- ‘apple’ needs to be apple
- ‘[apple]’ needs to be [apple]
- ‘(apple)’ needs to be (apple)

However: Apple’s needs to stay Apple’s because there is only one apostrophe.

How do I select both apostrophes when there is a word in between so I can delete them with re.sub? In every try I remove the entire string! Hopefully someone can help.

My code is as follows:

```
str_o='\'Apple\''

str_o_a = re.sub(r"\'(.*?)\'","", str_o)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have add my code

Comment: What happens with "He's his father's son"? Two apostrophes. Also, your examples use typographical apostrophes (`’`) not the ASCII ones (`'`) – is that important?

Comment: What should happen with `''apple''` (two apostrophes before and after)?

Comment: ''apple'' needs to be apple.

Comment: Okay, so consecutive apostrophes must also be removed. I still assume those typographical apostrophies in the question are a typo and you are looking to remove `'` (not `’`)?

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler idea: split by whitespace, trim leading and trailing apostrophes, join with whitespace. Avoids having to write a regular expression and handles sentences such as "She's 'her' mother's daughter".

```
text = "She's 'her' mother's daughter"
text = ' '.join([word.strip("'") for word in text.split()])
print(text)
# She's her mother's daughter
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the parentheses in your regular expression was probably to capture the string you want to keep.  The idiom looks like

```
str_o_a = re.sub(r"'([^']*)'", r"\1", str_o)
```

You want a raw string around the replacement, too, in order to preserve the backslash in the argument (otherwise you would be replacing with the literal string `"\x01"`).

Notice also the preference for using a negated character class over a non-greedy "match anything" wildcard.

Comment: So "She's 'her' mother's daughter" will become "Shes her mothers daughter"? Not sure if OP wants this as result

Comment: The question is fundamentally unclear around these corner cases, but thanks for the comment. I suppose `"'([^']+)'(=\W)'"` would work for those, but not for "so 'she's' her 'mother's' daughter"